# Replying to packets with scapy

Tags: networking, scapy, man-in-the-middle

For a POC, I need to create a MITM setup where I would listen to ICMP traffic on the interface and for all the ping commands received, I would send my own reply. So far with python scapy, I have been able to intercept all ICMP packets. How do I block the actual ping reply packets and send my own packets as reply?

My code looks like this

```
import scapy.all as scapy
import socket
from scapy.arch import get_if_hwaddr
from scapy.interfaces import get_if_list
from scapy.layers import http
from scapy.layers.inet import TCP, ICMP, IP
from scapy.layers.l2 import Ether
from uuid import getnode as get_mac

def sniffer(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_packet)

def process_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(ICMP):
        print("DUMP\n")
        print(packet.show(dump=True))
        print(packet[Ether].src)
        print(Ether().src)
        if packet[Ether].src == Ether().src:
            print("OUTGOING PACKET")
        else:
            print("INCOMING PACKET")


interface = "Wi-Fi"
sniffer(interface)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the ICMP reply is sent by host's IP stack you have to find a trick to prevent it to send the reply.  If you're working on a linux system, you can for example:

- Make the IP stack ignore echo request:

```sh
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

- Configure the firewall so that only the ICMP replies sent by scapy can be sent.  You can for example, put `XXX` as the payload of your ICMP reply in your scapy script and let the firewall only accept such ICMP reply packets.

Comment: Can we ignore echo requests for a particular single interface only?